# Can't restrict accepted CA roots via X509TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I am trying to write a custom `X509TrustManager` that will use the default system trust store, but allowing only a restricted set of trusted CA roots.

I am trying to do this by returning a modified list of accepted CA roots from the `getAcceptedIssuers` method, but this does not seem to work -- server certificates are accepted as valid even when the root certificate is not part of the list returned by `getAcceptedIssuers`.

Here is a simple implementation that delegates to the system's default trust manager, but overrides `getAcceptedIssuers` to return an empty array:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class DefaultTrustManagerWrapper implements X509TrustManager {
    private final X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager;

    public DefaultTrustManagerWrapper() throws Exception {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init((KeyStore) null); // Init with default keystore

        // Find the X509TrustManager instance from the array of trust managers
        X509TrustManager foundTrustManager = null;
        for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
            if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tm;
            }
        }

        if (defaultTrustManager == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No X509TrustManager found");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        defaultTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        defaultTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        // Return no accepted issuers
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

But when using this, server certificates still validate OK.

Why is this happening? Isn't `getAcceptedIssuers` called by default when validating a server certificate?

Comment: The actual validation of the server or client certificate happens in the checkServerTrusted/checkClientTrusted method. So returning an empty list from getAcceptedIssuers won't work. What you can do in your wrapper class is to get the leaf certificate and pass that to the check method of the defaultTrustManager. That will exclude the intermediate and root ca when validation

Comment: I assumed checkServerTrusted would rely on getAcceptedIssuers. What is getAcceptedIssuers for, then?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489400/450398) to a related question, `getAcceptedIssuers` is not used to decide whether to trust a certificate. So that would explain the behaviour I am seeing.

The linked answer also includes some additional detail on when is `getAcceptedIssuers` actually used.